# Loop through array, use each value to filter other records in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, express

I have an array of stories, now i want to loop through it, get each key and value and pass it to the render. In the Stories array i have a field called `story_category_id`. I am only able to pass one ID in the function, I need to get all categories of all collected stories.

```
router.get('/', (request, response, next) => {
    Story.getAllStories((error, stories) => {
        StoryCategory.getAllStoryCategories((error, story_categories) => {
            Story.getStoryCategoryById(WHATTOPUTHERE, (error, story_category) => {
                response.render('./stories/all_stories', {
                    section_name: "All Stories",
                    stories: stories,
                    story_category: story_category,
                    story_categories: story_categories,
                });
            })
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your question needs more clearification.
can you show what you are trying to achieve.

To my understanding, Your function would only return one page. that is `./stories/all_stories` page.

Comment: you need to mention what these function do:
`Story.getAllStories`, `StoryCategory.getAllStoryCategories` & `Story.getStoryCategoryById`...

Comment: you do realize that you can only render one thing at a time. so a response can only contain one render call and then your response would end.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed returning one page. 
I want to get single_story_category_id from the stories array, then pass it to the getStoryCategoryById() method.

Comment: // Get all stories
module.exports.getAllStories=(callback) => {
  Story.find({}).sort([['story_title', 'ascending']]).exec(callback)
}

// Get all story categories
module.exports.getAllStoryCategories=(callback) => {
  StoryCategory.find({}).sort([['story_category_title', 'ascending']]).exec(callback)
}

module.exports.getStoryCategoryById=(id, callback) => {
  StoryCategory.findById(id, callback);
}

Comment: whats your `node` version?

Comment: It's version is 8.2.1

Comment: answered your question, You may ask if you find anything confusing, I have used ES6 standards

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get rid of callback style and learn to use promises. Also your function only takes `module.exports.getStoryCategoryById` only one ID while you need to process an array of ID. so you can improve your functions like this..

`my-module.js`

```
// Get all stories 
module.exports.getAllStories = () => Story.find({})
    .sort([['story_title', 'ascending']]).exec();

// Get all story categories 
module.exports.getAllStoryCategories = () => StoryCategory.find({})
    .sort([['story_category_title', 'ascending']]).populate('story_category_title').exec();

module.exports.getStoryCategoryById = (id) => StoryCategory.findById(id)
    .exec();
```

then you can define your router like this...

```
router.get('/', async (request, response, next) => {
    try {    
        const stories = await Story.getAllStories();
        const story_categories = await StoryCategory.getAllStoryCategories();
        // mapping stories to take out all the categories within that story.
        const story_category = await Story
           .getStoryCategoryById(stories[0].story_category_id);
        response.render('./stories/all_stories', {
             section_name: "All Stories",
             stories, // each story will have its own category..
             story_category,
             story_categories,
        });

    } catch(err) {
        next(err)
    }
});
```

### Edited

Changed this line of code from previous version, now it will only load one category of a story.

```
 const story_category = await Story
     .getStoryCategoryById(stories[0].story_category_id);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and helping me sir.

I just tried your solution, but now story_category returns an array of objects. Is it possible to get a specific one for the story and only then pass it to the view?

Comment: @MherMargaryan I have changed the code, please see the mentioned code, you can use it, and your problem would be solved hopefully, if it works, please mark the answer

Comment: Thank you again, but stories[0] returns just the first index, and it will be the same thing for everyone else.

Comment: so for which story you want it specific to?
do you want every story to has its category embedded?

Comment: the best would be,
If you can edit your question,
To show me expected output.